# How to link view config to view model declarative in Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs6

Currently when defining a config like this:

```
config: {
  foo: null
}
```

I have put in a `updateFoo` method to update viewModel:

```
updateFoo: function(nVal, oVal) {
    this.viewModel.set('foo', nVal);
}
```

Quenstion: Is there a way to link `foo` in `config` with `viewModel` declaratively ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for has a solution of "formulas".
In View Model you could write a formula to update your foo in config directly whenever its necessary. For now i am telling you how to update "foo" whenever your view model/view is loaded.

Write a formula as below in ViewModel

```
formulas: {
    example: {
        get:function(get) {
            this.getConfig().foo=/whatever value u want to update/;
        }
    }
}
```

If I am not getting it properly then please ellaborate your problem.

Comment: The config you getting there is the config passed to constructor at runtime when your component is consumed, the config I mentioned about was different [Class config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-config)

Comment: Okay.. I think so your question is that how you update foo in config directly via viewmodel via two-way binding so that u dont need to call updateFoo everytime. I mean whenever the foo value is changed it should be updated automatically?

Comment: You understood it the reversed way. It was to link a view bindable property to the viewModel, so that you dont have to update the viewModel everytime. This happens when your comp is used inside others components.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, it has to be used together with `publishes` and `bind`

For the example in the question:

```
config: {
  foo: null
},

// This makes `foo` visible to `viewModel`
publishes: {
  foo: true
},

bind: {
  foo: '{vmFoo}'
}
```